# Linear gradient doesn't work in Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm nearly done with my website, but now I'm checking browsers compatibility and have some problems with Safari. I resolved some of them, but this can't.

I'm using this code to add background for my textarea

```
background-image: 
linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 79px, #abced4 79px, #abced4 81px, transparent 81px),
linear-gradient(#126d82 .1em, transparent .1em);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 79px, #126d82 79px, #126d82 81px, transparent 81px),
-webkit-linear-gradient(#126d82 .1em, transparent .1em);
background-size: 100% 2em;
background-position: 30px 31px;
```

This all works as I expected in all browsers except Safari. I tried something with -webkit-linear-gradient but doesn't help.

What can I do to make this work?

Thank you.

This is link to my website so you can see difference http://motiongiraffx.com/

Comment: Which version of safari?

Comment: Is your code supposed to output notebook paper? I tested the code in Firefox and got something that looks like notebook paper.

Comment: I'm testing in 5.1.7. Safari. Yes it should show something like notebook paper.

Comment: I was able to achieve something similar in Safari with: `linear-gradient(270deg, #FFF 16.34%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);`.

Answer (score 1):

Safari 5.1.7 is quite old. (Current version is 8.0.7.) I'm not sure how Safari versions sync up with WebKit versions, but original Safari support used a different syntax for `linear-gradient`:

```
-webkit-gradient(<type>, <point> [, <radius>]?, <point> [, <radius>]? [, <stop>]*)
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) has more information.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 5.1.7. is an older version of safari and that's why it doesn't work (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients)).

The best way when working with `linear-gradient` is to use some online generator, like [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), which does all the work for you and keeps in mind for older browsers.

See the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Gradients/Gradient.html):

> Note: Recent drafts of the W3C proposal have simplified the syntax. This chapter describes the most recent implementation shipping in Safari. You should expect Safari’s syntax for gradients to continue to change as the W3C standard evolves. While new syntax is expected, the existing syntax—and prior syntax—should still work.
>
> The `-webkit-linear-gradient` and `webkit-radial-gradient` properties require iOS 5.0 or later, or **Safari 5.1 or later** on the desktop. If you need to support earlier releases of iOS or Safari, see Prior Syntax (`-webkit-gradient`).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #color1, #color2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `-linear` from both instances of `-webkit-linear-gradient`. With that change, I got the 'notebook' effect in both Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reduce all the vendor prefixes (and make life easier in general) you can get going with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/). Once you use some of the includes available, the vendor prefixing occurs automatically, and helps with a lot of these browser-specific issues.

For example:

```
@include background(linear-gradient(red, green) left repeat);
```